# Determine UIInterfaceOrientation of UIViewController without [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have some code where I used to use `presentingViewController.interfaceOrientation` to determine the supported interface orientations of the current `UIViewController`. Due to `interfaceOrientation` being deprecated, I've since replaced that code with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` and it works fine. However, in iOS9 and iOS8, it does not work (I get some really funny results when I check for the orientation in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, `supportedInterfaceOrientations`, and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`).

So I was wondering, is there anyway to determine the interface orientation of a view controller without using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`? (needing to differntiate between landscape left and right, and portrait right side up and upside down).

Comment: Were you able to get an answer for this?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I can't remember. As I look at my code, I'm using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] like I stated above, so not sure what I did to fix the issue in iOS9 and iOS8.

Answer (score 0):

You can check orientation using

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                            duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) == YES) {
    // landscape
}
else {
    // portrait.
}
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using UIDevice to get the orientation as its behavior is a little different than getting it from the status bar.